# ERROR while spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am getting below error while submitting my application on AWS EMR system. Submitting spark application in client mode works fine. Please let me know if there are anyother configurations that needs to be done inorder to work this in cluster mode in aws emr.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-81-182 ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1G --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false --class WordCount.word.App /home/hadoop/word.jar s3n://bucket1/text.txt s3n://bucket1/output/ s3n://bucket1/analysis1/user.parquet
18/12/13 11:26:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-81-182.ec2.internal/172.31.81.182:8032
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (6144 MB per container)
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
18/12/13 11:26:07 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
18/12/13 11:26:09 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
18/12/13 11:26:11 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-e01877e4-eb8c-4f6a-a6f5-c5c769c9c21e/__spark_libs__2272513134347036396.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-81-182.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1544697633631_0011/__spark_libs__2272513134347036396.zip
18/12/13 11:26:13 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/word.jar -> hdfs://ip-172-31-81-182.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1544697633631_0011/word.jar
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-e01877e4-eb8c-4f6a-a6f5-c5c769c9c21e/__spark_conf__8515846431603225843.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-81-182.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1544697633631_0011/__spark_conf__.zip
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/12/13 11:26:15 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1544697633631_0011 to ResourceManager
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1544697633631_0011
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1544697633631_0011 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: [Thu Dec 13 11:26:16 +0000 2018] Application is Activated, waiting for resources to be assigned for AM.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION> ; Partition Resource = <memory:6144, vCores:4> ; Queue's Absolute capacity = 100.0 % ; Queue's Absolute used capacity = 0.0 % ; Queue's Absolute max capacity = 100.0 % ;
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1544700376013
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-81-182.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1544697633631_0011/
         user: hadoop
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-e01877e4-eb8c-4f6a-a6f5-c5c769c9c21e
18/12/13 11:26:16 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-0762aaf6-577a-4ad7-a4a1-c4c16a590feb
[hadoop@ip-172-31-81-182 ~]$
```

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot; Does this work, if you get rid of your executor-memory flag on the spark-submit? Asking this since when executor-memory is hardcoded in the application, it would explain the result you've shared.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, Tried the same but no luck..

Comment: @Jack can you share the command which you are using to submit the job on yarn

Comment: @arcticOak2 its the first line of the above output- [hadoop@ip-172-31-81-182 ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1G --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false --class WordCount.word.App /home/hadoop/word.jar s3n://bucket1/text.txt s3n://bucket1/output/ s3n://bucket1/analysis1/user.parquet

Comment: @Jack can you share the yarn logs using the command : yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>. For above run <application ID> will be application_1544697633631_0011.

Comment: @HarshBafna thanks or pointing out to yarn logs, my EMR was running in private VPC coz of which i was not able to access yarn logs, but after verification using above mention command, i found that issue was something different my parameter/argument was in json, length of that was exceeding coz of which step was getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the actual logs message while executing the spark job in yarn-cluster mode use the following command :

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```

For the above run  will be application_1544697633631_0011.